# ES6 Accessing child class's `this` when overriding a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have following code:

```
class BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    // BELOW LINE CALLS OVERRIDDEN FUNCTION BUT WITH `this` OF BaseClass
    this.preHook(); 
  }

  // THIS FUNCTION IS BEING OVERRIDDEN IN CHILD CLASS
  preHook(data) {
   return data;
  }
}


class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.someKey = 'someValueFromChild';
   }
   preHook(data) {
      console.log('this.someKey', this.someKey); //IT PRINTS undefined
   }
}


var c = new ChildClass();

OUTPUT:
this.someKey undefined

Expecting
this.someKey someValueFromChild
```

So in BaseClass's constructer i am calling a function `this.preHook()` which is getting overridden in ChildClass, when we initialise ChildClass it calls BaseClass's constructer and then it calls `this.preHook`'s overridden version , but instead of printing `someValueFromChild` which is defined in child class, it is printing undefined (it is using `this` of parent class instead of child`.

How can i make it to use `this` of child class.

Comment: ES5 doesn't have classes. This is ES6 code

Comment: `someKey` was never defined, neither in the parent class, nor in the ChildClass thus it can not be anything else but `undefined`

Comment: @messerbill someKey is defined in constructor of child class.

Comment: @JeremyThille . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes says that its introduced in ECMA 2015

Comment: `says that its introduced in ECMA 2015`  Yep, that's not ES5

Comment: ECMA 2015, aka ES6.

Comment: Do `this` and then do `super`..

Comment: @Keith you can't do this, the parent class is not initialize before `super`, so neither is `this`

Comment: @JeremyThille edited question title and tags to use es6.

Comment: @Kaddath  good point, using a constructor args might be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i make it to use `this` of child class.

There is no "`this` of child class." There is only **one** object (backed by its prototype objects). `this` within `BaseClass` and `this` within `ChildClass` both refer to the **same** object.

The reason accessing `this.someKey` results in `undefined` in that code is that the child constructor doesn't set `someKey` until **after** the parent constructor is finished — and the parent constructor calls `preHook`, so `preHook` is called before the child constructor sets `someKey`. So there is no `someKey` property at all as of when `preHook` tries to read it from the object. You'd see this if you stepped through the code with a debugger. Here's an annotated version showing what happens when:

```js
class BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log("BaseClass constructor start");
    this.preHook(); 
    console.log("BaseClass constructor finish");
  }

  // THIS FUNCTION IS BEING OVERRIDDEN IN CHILD CLASS
  preHook(data) {
    console.log("BaseClass.preHook called");
    return data;
  }
}


class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   constructor() {
     console.log("ChildClass constructor start");
     super();
     console.log("ChildClass constructor setting `someKey`");
     this.someKey = 'someValueFromChild';
     console.log("ChildClass constructor finish");
   }
   preHook(data) {
      console.log("ChildClass.preHook called");
      console.log('this.someKey', this.someKey);
   }
}

var c = new ChildClass();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Calling overrideable methods from a constructor is a well-established anti-pattern — and this is part of the reason. :-) Instead, don't have the parent constructor call `preHook`. Do it *after* construction.

There are workarounds, but the best option by far is to not have the `BaseClass` constructor call `preHook` at all. How you do that in your code obviously depends on the greater context of your code, so I can't give you an example.

Comment: he want the childclass`prehook` called on the parent class.how thats possible?inheritance inthe wrong order?

Comment: @zabusa it is possible if the parent constructor has an argument to pass the value of `someKey` at construction, before `preHook` is called, then

Comment: @Kaddath wat?that we can call it in the childclass right.why you need parent to call a child class function?

Comment: @zabusa: *"he want the childclassprehook called on the parent class"* Not sure what you mean by "on" there. If you meant "in", that's what's happening, because `this.preHook` where `this` is referring to the object will get `preHook` from the object if it has it or from its immediate prototype, or its prototype's prototype, etc. In the code in the question, the object `this` references (everywhere it's used in that code) refers to the object created by `new ChildClass` which means its prototype is assigned from `ChildClass.prototype`. So it's the `ChildClass` `preHook`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ohh.got it. but.we use this kind of model in real life?

Comment: @zabusa: As I said in the answer: Calling overrideable methods from a constructor is a well-established anti-pattern.

Comment: Another good reason not to do it in the constructor is for async reasons,..  I usually create a function say called `init`, as constructors can't be Promises..

Answer (score 2):

There is race condition that the consequence of natural limitations of ES6 classes. `this` should always appear after `super()` in child constructor. Since `this.preHook()` is called in parent constructor (`super`), there's no way how `this.someKey` can be assigned in constructor and appear during `this.preHook()` call.

Otherwise `this.preHook()` call should happen in child constructor only, this defies the concept of hooks and prevents child class from being properly extended.

In order to avoid race condition, `someKey` should be defined on class prototype, thus `super` and `this` precedence is no longer a problem:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }

    get someKey() {
      return 'someValueFromChild';
    }
    ...
}
```

The alternative that allows to maintain proper class lifecycle is to implement hooks on application level, like it's usually done in JS frameworks. Hookable classes should be instantiated through certain interface and never directly, i.e:

```
function instantiateWithHooks(cls, args) {
  const instance = new cls(...args);
  instance.preHook();
  return instance;
}
```

As explained in another answer, when child class is instantiated, there is only one `this`, which is (usually) an instance of child class.

Comment: It won't work well in all cases, e.g. for non-primitive props. But I agree that for string constant it's perfectly ok.